# Alexa Smart Home device or skill discovery

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Does Amazon provide an API that will return a list of the Smart Home skills (or devices) that are currently linked to the user's account? You can get this list and actually control the devices from the Amazon Alexa mobile app, but I was wondering if this capability is exposed in a public API?

The device discovery interface looks similar to what I am looking for, but I believe this is provided only as an interface that needs to be supported when building a skill: 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html

I'd like to be able to discover the smart home devices currently attached to a user account and display them in a mobile app.